# Reversing a slice of a Python string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, text

I am trying to get this string to read backwards, however I am having trouble shifting it to start iterating back from `h` instead of `g` without changing the variables `text`, `start` and `end`?

```
text = 'abcdefghij'
start = 1
end = 7
back = text [start:end] [::-1]
print back
```

The result I get is `gfedcb` but what I want is `hgfedc`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to slice twice.

```
>>> text[end:start:-1]
'hgfedc'
```

As a bonus, switching the order of `start` and `end` also switches the open/closed end of the range so you don't have to add or subtract 1 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
>>> print text[start+1:end+1][::-1]
hgfedc
```